# Is there tutorial creation software like WINK?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for a tutorial creation software like WINK in Ubuntu 11.10 (WINK is not in the repositories). Is there anything I can use, that is easy to learn, exports to flash, and possible has audio capability, and of course works in Ubuntu versions (current and upcoming)?

Answer (score 4):

There are different applications to record screencasts under Ubuntu. They may not allow creating flash videos directly, but usually you can convert the screencast to flash in a separate step.

Here's a list of applications that are available via apt:

- [Byzanz](http://packages.ubuntu.com/Byzanz) [image: Install Byzanz] (creating GIF)
- [Istanbul](http://packages.ubuntu.com/Istanbul) [image: Install Istanbul] (OGG)
- [recordMyDesktop](http://packages.ubuntu.com/recordMyDesktop) [image: Install recordMyDesktop] (OGG)
- [RecordItNow](http://packages.ubuntu.com/RecordItNow) [image: Install RecordItNow] (multiple formats)
- [XVidCap](http://packages.ubuntu.com/XVidCap) [image: Install XVidCap]

You may even use VLC Media Player to record screencasts.

See also the [Ubuntu Wiki on Screencasts in general](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ScreenCasts) and on [creating Screencasts](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CreatingScreencasts), especially using [Istanbul](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ScreenCasts/Istanbul), [RecordMyDesktop](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ScreenCasts/RecordMyDesktop), [XVidCap](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ScreenCasts/XVidCap) and [FFmpeg](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ScreenCasts/ffmpeg).

**EDIT:**

There seems to be almost no application that allows for creating interactive tutorials or screencasts. There's only one [project named Salasaga](http://www.salasaga.org) (see also [Salasaga on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/salasaga)) that looks very promising, but it's still in it's alpha stage.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! However, I am looking for an INTERACTIVE software, something with an easy way to attach buttons and actions to slides and movies. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @sabinedoll: ah, ok - AFAIK none of the tools i've listed allow for creating interactice screencasts. Sadly, i don't know any other software in the ubuntu repos that offer such a functionality. So i fear the only option is to install the Linxu version of WINK.

Comment: @sabinedoll: i've edited my answer, maybe Salasage would be useful for you.